# lambda tkinter not. able to return value from button callback

Tags: tkinter, button, lambda

I am trying to get a return value from a button using lambda but the value returned is not getting updated. Can someone else help in finding the reason, I am new to python and may be facing an obvious issue.

```
B = Button(newWindow[num], text="Change Direction",
                   command=lambda: clk == change_direction_dummy(CLOCK,))
B.grid(row=4, column=2)
B.after(2000, B.destroy())

******Callback function 

def change_direction_dummy(clk):
    print(f"Changing Message direction{clk}")
    if clk == 0:
        clk = 1
    else:
        clk = 0
    print(f"returning clk {clk}")
    return(clk)
```

Comment: Try using `setattr()` in the lambda.

Comment: Instead of returning value from function, make the variable `clk` or `CLOCK` (whichever you are updating) as `global`, and then in function `change_direction_dummy()` you can set the value of the global variable

Comment: ```lambda: clk == change_direction_dummy(CLOCK,)``` I don't understand this?

Comment: For passing an arguments ```lambda: change_direction_dummy(CLOCK,)```

Comment: First `==` is comparison, not assignment.  Second assignment statement is not allow inside `lambda`.  You can either using global variable, or change `CLOCK` to `tkinter.IntVar` so that you can use `lambda: CLOCK.set(change_direction_dummy(CLOCK.get()))`.